# Black stains on aluminium+teflon griddle

Tags: kitchen-safety, teflon, griddle

I have an old aluminium griddle with teflon siding. The griddle is covered with black stains that look like grease stains but won't go away by washing. I can scrape them away but I am afraid that this would damage the griddle. Is it safe to use it? Is there a way to remove the stains?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its not ideal, but it's fine. It's burned on oil or grease. If you haven't used it for a while, it can impart a slightly musty flavour to your food.

A suggestion for cleaning - heat the pan whilst dry, then lightly spray with a cleaner & use a bristled brush to clean it whilst very hot.

Comment: What kind of cleaner do you suggest?